# Why is this call to a simple helper function causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, global-variables, infinite-loop, helper

I've been debugging this for hours to no avail.

The following code checks whether each number in a series of numbers has no repeating digits ( `111` should return `false`; `123` should return `true`) and return an array of all numbers in the series which contain no repeating digits.

The array should be populating with values which the helper function returns as `true` for each value in the array, but running `noRepeats()` causes an infinite loop or a long array of 1s. What is causing this?

```js
// DO NOT RUN AS IS; POTENTIAL INFINITE LOOP

var noRepeatDigits = function (n) {
  n = n.toString();
  for ( i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i ++ ) {
    for ( j = i + 1 ; j < n.length ; j ++ ) {
      if ( n.charAt(i) === n.charAt(j) ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log( noRepeatDigits(113) ); // false
console.log( noRepeatDigits(123) ); // true

var noRepeats = function (n1, n2) {
  var arr = [];
  for ( i = n1 ; i <= n2 ; i ++ ) {
    if ( noRepeatDigits(i) ) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

console.log( noRepeats(1, 100) );
```

Comment: Well. Set a breakpoint and debug your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `var i`, so the iterator is global and the two functions using it overwrite each other. This causes unexpected behaviour at best, an infinite loop at worst.

However you can simplify your `noRepeatDigits` function a lot:

```
noRepeatDigits = function(n) {
    return !n.toString().match(/(.).*?\1/);
};
```

This effectively does what your original function did, but offloads the heavy work to built-in, lower-level functions which generally speaking are significantly faster.

Comment: Declaring `i` as a local variable with `var i` solved my problem, thanks. Using regex matching really does simplify things, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addon to Niet the Dark Absol's answer.

As pointed out by him the unexpected behavior was caused by the variables used in your loop. I would recommend you to put the `"use strict";` hint at the top of your Javascript. That way you will not make the same kind of mistake again.

Example:

```
"use strict";
// DO NOT RUN AS IS; POTENTIAL INFINITE LOOP

var noRepeatDigits = function (n) {
    n = n.toString();
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i ++ ) {
        for ( var j = i + 1 ; j < n.length ; j ++ ) {
            if ( n.charAt(i) === n.charAt(j) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

**Quote:**
Converting mistakes into errors

> Strict mode changes some previously-accepted mistakes into errors.
>   JavaScript was designed to be easy for novice developers, and
>   sometimes it gives operations which should be errors non-error
>   semantics. Sometimes this fixes the immediate problem, but sometimes
>   this creates worse problems in the future. Strict mode treats these
>   mistakes as errors so that they're discovered and promptly fixed.
>
> **First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"**
>   (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript).
>   Assignments which would accidentally create global variables instead
>   throw in strict mode:

**See:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: @JamesBecker you might be interested in this also.

Comment: I needed someone to tell me this. I knew about `'use strict'` but no one I know implements it. Maybe I should find better friends. Thanks!